# cross_val_score returns nan when put in fit_params

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am doing SVC for classification task with cross validation using cross_val_score in slearn, but turns out it return list of nan value when I put in parameters for fit_params but working fine if I dont put in the parameters for fit_params.

Code:

```
# define parameter
param_grid = {
    'C' : [1,5,10,20],
    'gamma' : ['auto','scale']
}

svc = SVC(kernel = "rbf")

scores = cross_val_score(svc, x_train, y_train, cv=10, fit_params = param_grid)
# scores output array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan])

scores = cross_val_score(svc, x_train, y_train, cv=10)
# scores output array([0.95833333, 0.95833333, 0.95454545, 0.93181818, 0.95454545, 0.96197719, 0.96197719, 0.94676806, 0.96197719, 0.95057034])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fit_params` is designated for `fit` methods (e.g., array of sample weights for training data), but you pass your parameter grid to [`cross_val_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html), which is incompatible with your data (`x_train`, `y_train`, etc.). Indeed, if you specify `error_score='raise'` in your `cross_val_score`, you will receive the corresponding error. Parameter grids should be used with [`GridSearchCV`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) or similar tools.

Answer (score 1):

svc cannot accept the X_train and Y_train
for on put
you should import  GridSearchCV
fit data and continue

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).